# Blacksmith or Dungeons, which is better to upgrade?

Tags: heroville

I've been keeping my Dungeon and Blacksmith levels the same since they cost roughly equal amounts to upgrade.  However, I usually have to upgrade one, wait, then upgrade the other.

Which upgrade offers a better increase in sales?  Should I offer the higher level dungeon first so heroes need to buy more potions and other items that are already fully stocked (and presumably make more form the higher level), or is it better to upgrade the Blacksmith first and have heroes slowly begin buying the better weapons so they can clear the current dungeon faster?

Answer (score 1):

The blacksmith offers the best direct upgrade in terms of profit. Heroes will always want to buy the best weapon they can.

The dungeons should be upgraded when heroes are not gaining any more experience at the current dungeon level or you feel that a hero with the current weapon does not have any chance of having that weapon break.